# Elasticsearch security measures?

Tags: security, rest, elasticsearch, logstash

I have set up my ELK stack on a single server and tested it on a very small setup to get a hands-down on ELK.
I want to use ELK for my system logs analysis.

Now, I have been reading about ES that it has no security. Also read something like this:
"DO NOT have ES publicly accessible. That's the equivalent of making your Wordpress MySQL database accessible to the world. ES is a REST accessible DB which means that anyone can delete all of your data with access to the endpoint."

I am a noob in this. So this means if I put my logs in ES will they be accessible to everyone (which is scary) ??

Please guide me with what all security measures must be taken? Please suggest some links so that I can ensure security.
How to keep my ES cluster private?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Security is a real subject in ELK stack .

The initial position of elasticsearch is : we don't care about security , do it your self , ACL Hosts .....

With the success of ELK and the demands about security : elasticsearch is finally realizing that's the security is a real subject .

They are developping this : 
http://www.elasticsearch.com/products/shield/

You can see : `SOON` so this is not released yet  .

So for now i see two solutions :

- Secure you Kibana : KIbana is hosted in a webserver (Apache , Nginx) so you can add security in the web server layer . In this case your B&ackend(Elastic search) is not yet secured , you add security only in the client Side(Kibana) . So every one can access directelly to your ES server REST API and GET/POST/DELETE/PUT Data .
- Secure your Elasticsearch : There is several plugins that enable Security in ES

  - https://github.com/salyh/elasticsearch-security-plugin
  - https://github.com/sonian/elasticsearch-jetty
  - https://github.com/codelibs/elasticsearch-auth